# MOT advisories: slight brake bind and surface corrosion outer sills?

Tags: corrosion

I'm looking into buying a 2004 Daihatsu Sirion. It has low mileage (50,000) and from all accounts has been well looked after. On its most recent MOT it had two advisories:

"Slight brake bind osf" and
"Surface corrosion started on both outer sills"

How concerned should I be about these? What can be done about either of these things and how costly might it be?

Answer (score 1):

The slight brake bind osf isn't much to worry about. Best case its just the calliper sliders have gone tight/seized or the pads have gone tight in the calliper. Worst case it is the brake calliper which would be anything from £65-£150 plus one to two hours labour.

The surface corrosion on the sill could just be that 'surface corrosion' but I would say there is a strong chance of further rust as the Sirion is known for bad rust along the inner/outer sills and near the rear suspension mounts. I would try to take a good look underneath and have a good prod with a screw driver/pick and tap any suspect areas with a hammer. Good metal should make a sharp metallic sound whereas a corroded area with sound dull and hollow.

Answer (score 0):

We don't do prices, but the brake bind may only be a sticking caliper - so a brake service and the sills may only need cleaning preping and painting so ask your local garage...

Both jobs may be something you may wish to attempt and, especially for the brakes, something that you may need advice / checking depending on your skills.